# Byte order mark removal in xml files using Java IO

Tags: java

The byte order mark is the first 3 bytes in my xml file. How do I remove the Byte order mark from the xml file programmatically? I want to completely discard it.

Comment: could you paste the beginning of your xml file here?

Comment: þÿ<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>

Answer (score 1):

Rather than removing it, I use a special reader which reacts properly to BOM (and uses proper encoding, based on read BOM): I copied it from elsewhere (see note inside) but it is open-sourced in my android-menu-navigator project:

http://code.google.com/p/android-menu-navigator/source/browse/src/pl/polidea/navigator/UnicodeReader.java

You can use this reader anyway to read content of XML and write it elsewhere, effectively removing the BOM.